# SimpleTagSupport Vs TagSupport in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want create Tag in jsp and I don't know the difference between this two class SimpleTagSupport and TagSupport  for create tag in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

It is all explained in the Javadocs:

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTagSupport.html

> "A base class for defining tag handlers implementing `SimpleTag`."

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.html

> "A base class for defining new tag handlers implementing `Tag`. "

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/SimpleTag.html

> "Simple Tag Handlers differ from Classic Tag Handlers in that instead of supporting `doStartTag()` and `doEndTag()`, the `SimpleTag` interface provides a simple `doTag()` method, which is called once and only once for any given tag invocation. All tag logic, iteration, body evaluations, etc. are to be performed in this single method. Thus, simple tag handlers have the equivalent power of `BodyTag`, but with a much simpler lifecycle and interface.

---

In summary, `SimpleTags` (added in JSP 2.0) are simpler to implement than `Tags`.